# Saving Array<NSValue> in CoreData as Transformable Attribute

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an app using CoreData with an entity that has a Transformable attribute.
The attribute is of type Array.

As these are compliant with NSCoding, I never had any problems saving this entity.

Today, I ran into an issue saving these entities which I never had a problem with in the past.

*value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'NSValue'*

I don't know if a recent update broke this, but all of the sudden I cannot save my entity with the transformable attribute of type Array.

No idea where the problem came from. It has been working for a long time.

Why am I now getting an error trying to access an entity with a transformable attribute of type Array ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save an array of objects (like String), set *Custom Class* as **[String]**.

You also can set values as [Data], and later get object with decoding it.

[image]

Comment: I do in fact have Custom Class set to [NSValue] and still have this problem.